# In Android Studio 0.8.6, all the import statements say Cannot Resolve Symbol?

Tags: android

```
import android.app.Activity;//activity is in red

import android.os.Bundle;//bundle is in red
import android.view.Menu;//menu is in red
import android.view.MenuItem;//Menuitem is in red
import android.widget.Button;//Button is in red


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);//OnCreate is in red
//OnCreate is in red
```

It says it cannot resolve symbol for almost everything!
        `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to happen occasionally. Unfortunately, there are only a few things you can do.

First, try to clean the project...(Build -> Clean Project)

That, most likely, won't work. The next step would be to open your SDK manager (3rd button from the right) and download the latest build tools. This is very likely to work.

If that doesn't work, then you may just want to reinstall Android Studio. That's what I had to do two weeks ago.

Comment: When I redownloaded it, the same project and errors appeared.