# Can not resolve symbol error in import statements in Android Studio Project

Tags: android, import

[android studio code screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqYCw.png)

Some Android imports are showing...Cant resolve symbol. even though those classes are available in SDK/Sources/...|(Red color code in picture)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216218/in-android-studio-0-8-6-all-the-import-statements-say-cannot-resolve-symbol. I tried the solutions mentioned for that similar question, but errors not gone

Comment: Show us your gradle. I think you need to add dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup [support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)?

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29784452/2764443) is similar question.

You must setup support library same version of your project SDK version.

(ex. Android SDK version is `22`, you must import  `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+`)